# android recyclerview when adding new view by clicking a plus button previous views get refreshed

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like on click a plus button, add `RecyclerView` view and refresh the previous views.

Each view have spinner in it. So when clicking on plus button the previous spinner value should remain.

```
addNewAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override public void onClick(View v) { 
        addQuickActionDataList.add(position,new AddQuickActionData());
        AddNewQuickActionAdapter adapter = new AddNewQuickActionAdapter(
            NewQuickAction.this,addQuickActionD‌​ataList,uDeviceList,‌​
                uRoomList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter); 
        position++; 
    } 
});

@Override public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (holder instanceof MyViewHolder) {
        final AddQuickActionData list = (AddQuickActionData)addQuickActionDataList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code which is not working as expected

Comment: addNewAction.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                addQuickActionDataList.add(position,new AddQuickActionData());
                AddNewQuickActionAdapter adapter = new AddNewQuickActionAdapter(NewQuickAction.this,addQuickActionDataList,uDeviceList,uRoomList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                position++;
            }
        });

Comment: @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (holder instanceof MyViewHolder) {

            final AddQuickActionData list = (AddQuickActionData)addQuickActionDataList.get(position);